# How to get the API data in to the Text Element React Native

Tags: react-native

I have successfully done the API call and put data into an object. Now I want to put the API data into the `TEXT` element. following is my code & the data array. I want to show createdAt & tasks in Text element.Any suggestions will help a lot.
Thanks in advance

```
            (async () => {
            try{
            let ServiceTicketData = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
                    'deviceId': deviceId,
                    'sessionId': sessionId
        
                },
            });
            let STData = await ServiceTicketData.json();
            console.log("ST Data",STData);
            setServiceTData(STData);
            setRefreshing(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })()
            
        }, [refreshing]);
        
console.log("Newdata",ServiceTData);
```

My data Array:

```
Newdata Object {
  "data": Object {
    "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55",
    "tasks": Array [
      Object {
        "completed": false,
        "createdAt": null,
        "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
        "product": "PRINTER",
        "remark": "paper jam",
        "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
        "status": null,
        "topic": "21080295T210",
        "ttId": 27226,
        "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
      },
    ],
    "topic": null,
    "visitingAdd1": "J/ HARTLEY COLLEGE,",
    "visitingAdd2": "POINT PEDRO",
    "visitingAdd3": "POINT PEDRO",
  },
  "errorCode": null,
  "reason": "Successful",
  "success": true,
}
```

Now I want to put data into following

```
function RenderServiceTicket(ServiceTData){
    return ( 
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={{paddingTop: 10}}>
        <Card borderRadius={15} >
        <View>
            <Text>{ServiceTData.createdAt}</Text>
            <Text>{ServiceTData.tasks}</Text> <=== "*This should be in a List*"
        </View>
    </Card>
    </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tasks` in `ServiceTData` is an `Array`. You can use the `FlatList` component to render your list.

Replace

```js
<Text>{ServiceTData.tasks}</Text> <=== "*This should be in a List*"
```

with

```js
<FlatList
  data={ServiceTData?.data?.tasks || []}
  renderItem={({item}) =>
    // the flatlist will loop over your tasks array and you can access each 
    // element as item.
    (
      <View>
       <Text>{item?.model ?? ''}</Text>
       // display the data you want to show like above

       <Text>{item?.createdAt ??''}</Text> // added createdAt as said in comments. You can access all the values with the same approach.
      </View>
    )
  }
  keyExtractor={(item) => item. ttId}
/>
```

You can read more about `FlatList` at [FlatList React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

Also added `Optional Chaining` as from the response in your question, createdAt is null in one `task object`. The optional chaining will prevent your app from crashing.

You can change your `RenderServiceTicket` function to

```js
function RenderServiceTicket(ServiceTData){
  return ( 
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={{paddingTop: 10}}>
        <Card borderRadius={15} >
          <View>
            <Text>{ServiceTData?.data?.createdAt ?? '' }</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={ServiceTData?.data?.tasks || []}
              renderItem={({item}) =>
                // the flatlist will loop over your tasks array and you can access each 
                // element as item.
               (
                 <View>
                   <Text>{item?.model ?? ''}</Text>
                   // display the data you want to show like above

                   <Text>{item?.createdAt ??''}</Text> // added createdAt as said in comments. You can access all the values with the same approach.
                  </View>
                )
              }
              keyExtractor={(item) => item. ttId}
            />
          </View>
        </Card>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Adding [Live Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/flatlist-example)

Comment: This is Ok but how about i get "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55", <== this value?

Comment: You can access all the values inside the item object with `item.` the key of the item you want to access. I will add the createdAt value for your reference to my answer. If you are still confused... just lemme know

Comment: Need this value Newdata Object {
  "data": Object {
    "createdAt": "2021-08-06 13:27:55", <<=== this value

Comment: That part, you already have it fine on your code. No change required

Comment: Upon close inspection, it is `ServiceTData.data. createdAt`.

Comment: when i add <Text>{ServiceTData.data.createdAt}</Text> it shows as Error undefined is not an object

Comment: when i add {ServiceTData.createdAt} it won't show on screen

Comment: That must be coz during the initial state, the `ServiceTData` object doesn't have the `data` property inside of it. It has those state only after your api call and new state update. Can you try the updated answer, I've added optional chaining to avoid that error

Comment: When i add {ServiceTData.createdAt} it won't show on the screen any issue? It won't show the Flatlist even though

Comment: `ServiceTData`  doesn't have the property `createdAt`. instead it has a `data` object and then the `data` object has the `createdAt` property. That is why `{ServiceTData.createdAt}` is not working.

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/flatlist-example Take a look at this snack

Comment: I couldn't understand it please can you try to give a solution through my API data

Comment: I've updated the snack. copy and paste it in your project and see if it's clear now